# Complex SQL Join

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join

I am fairly new to SQL joins, but I have a tricky issue here. I have tried to resolve this on my own, and searched as well, but unsuccessful.

I have two primary SQL tables

**CustProfile**

```
ClientID || ClientName
```

**CustTransaction**

```
CorpID || DivID || DeptID
```

I need to display my output as follows:

```
`CorpID` `CorpIDClientName` `DivID` `DivIDName` `DeptID` `DeptIDName`  

CustTransaction.CorpID join on CustProfile.ClientID to get `CorpIDClientName`  
CustTransaction.DivID join on CustProfile.ClientID to get `DivIDName`  
CustTransaction.DeptID join on CustProfile.ClientID to get `DeptIDName`
```

I hope someone can provide the join query. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to edit this to make it clearer. Why in the world is the ClientID joined to the = to the CorpID, DivID AND DeptID??!!?

Comment: @GrayFox374 thanks, that is only what the question stated. I do not mean to comment on the quality of the database design.

Comment: To clarify for all, my previous comment referred to an edit I suggested to the question that includes example input and output. I do not have enough rep to edit without review. Also, I am not entirely certain that my interpretation is correct, but correct answers would need a more complete specification. The edit clarified requirements, as I understood. The question originator should check whether that is what he actually wanted.

Comment: @GrayFox374 sorry, I interpreted your comment as a review of my suggested edit, which in retrospect it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one:

```
SELECT  a.CorpID,
        b.ClientName AS CorpIDClientName,
        a.DivID,
        c.ClientName AS DivIDName,
        a.DeptID,
        d.ClientName AS DeptIDName
FROM    CustTransaction a
            INNER JOIN CustProfile b
                on a.CorpID = b.ClientID
            INNER JOIN CustProfile c
                on a.DivID = c.ClientID
            INNER JOIN CustProfile d
                on a.DeptID = d.ClientID
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I understanding correctly? You have Corporations, Divisions, and Departments all stored within the CustProfile table together.

So you are only joining the 2 different tables, but you need to join those 2 tables 3 separate times to get each of the different types of customer (Corp or Div or Dept)

If that's the case, what you need to do is alias the table that you are including multiple times so you can join it as if it were 3 separate tables, one for corps, one for divisions, and one for departments.

I'm not sure if the syntax would be the same in MSSQL, but for most SQL databases your join query would look something like this:

```
SELECT corps.ClientID CorpID, corps.ClientName CorpIDClientName,
       divs.ClientID DivID, divs.ClientName DivIDName,
       depts.ClientID DeptID, depts.ClientName DeptIDName
FROM CustProfile corps, CustProfile divs, CustProfile depts, CustTransaction t
WHERE t.CorpID = corps.ClientID 
  AND t.DivID = divs.ClientID
  AND t.DeptID = depts.ClientID
```

That should, I think, more or less do what you want...

Comment: Yes, for example corpID for a corp would be 101, and then divID for a division would be 102 and the deptID for the dept would be 103. It's a parent, child & grandchild relationship. The organization names are stored in the CustProfile table.

Comment: No, if this were a parent child and grandchild relationship, then ClientID would appear as the primary key in the 1st table and a foreign key in the second table.  And CorpID would be the primary key in the second table and a foreign key in a third table.  Your design needs work.